# Create a variable parameter list

Tags: php

Im looking for a bit of advice, I have visited [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) in the manual, however it might be the wrong page or I misinterpreted the instructions as I am still confused.

[image]

I have the following question about the assignment above.
I would like to know:

1. 1st and foremost what is a variable-length parameter?
2. Creating the function is not a problem however, how do I set the number of argumnets, since according to the question (if I understand it correctly) the function should be able to take any number of arguments. I guess it comes back to my 1st question regarding variable-length paramenters again...?

Thank you for reading

Comment: The term is "variable length parameter list". The "list" is the important thing here. It describes a function that can be called (used) with a variable number or parameters. You do not "set" the number of parameter somehow. You simply call the function with whatever list of parameters you want and leave it to the function to sort that out. php offers means to query the list of parameters a function was called with. A good example for such a function is php's `sprintf(...)`.

Comment: @arkascha thank you, am I correct if I say when I create the function, it will have no parameters i.e. `function nrs()`

Comment: Sure, you certainly can do that. Though often you want to the inital parameter(s) to be defined in an explicit manner. That has two advantages: 1. you can use type hinting for those first parameters which is a good thing for special, controlling parameters and 2. you enable modern IDEs to assist in a more constructive way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use variable length parameters on PHP you need the function [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.func-get-args.php) instead to define the parameters on function declaration. Your function look like this:

```
function foo()
{
    $params_count = func_num_args();
    $params_values = func_get_args();
}
```

On `$params_values` there are all parameters which were given to the `foo()` function. On `params_count` there is the number of parameters given to `foo()`. You can get the number of parameters given to the foo function with [`func_num_args()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.func-num-args.php)

**An example of using this functions (https://3v4l.org/TWd3v):**

```
function foo() {
    $params_count = func_num_args();
    var_dump($params_count);
    $params_values = func_get_args();
    var_dump($params_values);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> PHP has support for variable-length argument lists in user-defined
>   functions. This is implemented using the ... token in PHP 5.6 and
>   later, and using the func_num_args(), func_get_arg(), and
>   func_get_args() functions in PHP 5.5 and earlier.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Here is for 5.6+

```
<?php

function my_func(...$parameters)
{
    echo "There were ".count($parameters)." parameters passed:\n";

    foreach ($parameters as $a_parameter)
    {
        echo "Number ".$a_parameter."\n";
    }
}

echo my_func(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

?>
```

https://3v4l.org/QuJqD

In (even more) simple words:

The magic happens with the `...` token. `my_func` expects a **variable** number of parameters, which will be stored in the `$parameters` array. All that because of the `...` that precedes the `$parameters`. Then by using `count` on that `$parameter` array we get the **number** of the parameters stored in that array.

As Steven in the comments nicely put it: `my_func(...$parameters)` has a variable length parameter list **as opposed to a fixed-length parameter list which would look like `function my_func($param1, $param2, $param3, $param4, $param5)`** which would **always** expect **5** parameters.

Comment: as opposed to a fixed-length parameter list which would look like function my_func($param1, $param2, $param3, $param4, $param5)

Comment: @StevenManuel nicely put Steven i ll add it to the answer

Comment: I changed static-length to fixed-length which I think is better

Comment: @StevenManuel "fixed" fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Function can take variable numbers of arguments
You can use `func_get_args` to get all function arguments and works with them.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    function my_func(){
        $args = func_num_args();
        $args_list = func_get_args();
        echo 'There were '.$args.' numbers passed:<br>';
        foreach($args_list as $k=>$v){
            echo 'Number '.$v.'.<br>';
        }
    }

    my_func(1,2,3,4,5);
    my_func(3,4,5);
?>
```

Output 1:

```
There were 5 numbers passed:
Number 1.
Number 2.
Number 3.
Number 4.
Number 5.
```

Output 2:

```
There were 3 numbers passed:
Number 3.
Number 4.
Number 5.
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP supports variable-length function, inorder to achieve that functionality you need to create a function with no params and you can get get that params using PHP function `func_get_args()`

```
function noprms(){
    $count = func_num_args();
    $args = func_get_args();
    echo "There were $count arguments passed \n";
    echo "Number ".implode(",\nNumber ",$args)."\n";
}

noprms(1,2,3,4,5)."\n";
noprms(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)."\n";
```

[**Docs**](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)
[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://3v4l.org/H2jCj)

Answer (score 0):

I think the question refers to the triple dot notation: From the manual:

> In PHP 5.6 and later, argument lists may include the ... token to denote that the function accepts a variable number of arguments.

The variable arguments are accessible as an array (so you can loop them).

Copy paste from the manual:

```
<?php
function sum(...$numbers) {
$acc = 0;
foreach ($numbers as $n) {
    $acc += $n;
}
return $acc;
}

echo sum(1, 2, 3, 4);
```